# Appending <script> elements to div and execute dynamically with PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My sample php `$advert` variable as follows;

```
<script src="http://ad.example.com/scripts/rp.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://ad.example.com/scripts/rp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<"+"script src='http://ad.example.com/rpgetad.ashx?tt=t_&ciid=9775202&rnd="+Math.random()%99999999+"'></"+"script>");
</script>
```

I want to create js variable with it.

```
var advert = "<?php echo rawurlencode($advert); ?>";
```

then i want to decode and append it to specified div and execute it.

```
var content = decodeURIComponent(advert);
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = content;
```

But when i try it doesn't work.

I also tried php's `json_encode()` and `$('<div/>').html(contents).text()` decode methods.

**I need to do this with javascript if it is posible.**

I am caching html responses. Advertising codes from partners are changing every day. So i dont want to destroy page's cache every time. I am generating seperated js file with php to do that.

Comment: Why don't you just output the html directly in the php script, why go through the trouble of first putting it into javascript then adding it?

Comment: I am caching responses in redis. Advertising codes are randomly generated and i dont want to destroy cache every time.

Comment: Scripts aren't executed when you assign to `.innerHTML`. You need to use `document.createElement("script");`